# gnuplot : plotting graph with a base offset

Tags: bash, sed, awk, gnuplot

I have a file with some data as shown below.

```
1  0x5212cb03ca115ac0  0x3665fb5f1ac1
2  0x5212cb03ca115cc0  0x3665fb5f1ac7
3  0x5212cb03ca115ea0  0x3665fb5f1acd
4  0x5212cb03ca1160c0  0x3665fb5f1ad3
5  0x5212cb03ca1162a0  0x3665fb5f1ad9
6  0x5212cb03ca1164c0  0x3665fb5f1ade
7  0x5212cb03ca1166a0  0x3665fb5f1ae4
8  0x5212cb03ca1168a0  0x3665fb5f1aea
9  0x5212cb03ca116aa0  0x3665fb5f1af0
10  0x5212cb03ca116ca0  0x3665fb5f1af6
11  0x5212cb03ca116ea0  0x3665fb5f1afc
12  0x5212cb03ca1170a0  0x3665fb5f1b02
13  0x5212cb03ca117280  0x3665fb5f1b08
14  0x5212cb03ca117480  0x3665fb5f1b0e
15  0x5212cb03ca117680  0x3665fb5f1b14
16  0x5212cb03ca1178a0  0x3665fb5f1b1a
17  0x5212cb03ca117a80  0x3665fb5f1b20
18  0x5212cb03ca117c80  0x3665fb5f1b26
19  0x5212cb03ca117e80  0x3665fb5f1b2c
20  0x5212cb03ca118080  0x3665fb5f1b31
21  0x5212cb03ca118280  0x3665fb5f1b37
22  0x5212cb03ca118480  0x3665fb5f1b3d
```

I am attempting to plot a graph between `column 1 AND column 2` and `column 1 and column 3`.
Now the values in columns 2 and columns 3 are in strict ascending order.I want the graph to be scaled in such a way that ROW 0 of column 2 and column 3 are treated as base value OR '0'
and I want both the graphs 
'column 1 AND column 2' and 'column 1 AND column 3' to be plotted in the same graph so that I can compare the slopes of the two graphs.A template plt file that I am working with is given below

```
#!/bin/bash

set terminal pngcairo size 1280,960 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'

set xlabel "seq number"
set ylabel "timestamp"

set title "ts vs sequence number"

set key reverse Left outside
set grid

set pointsize 1.0
set style data linespoints

set output 'erf_ts_plot.png'
plot "output.txt" using 1:2 title "erf_ts"
set output 'ixia_ts_plot.png'
plot "output.txt" using 1:3 title "ixia_ts"
~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the values of the first row you can use e.g. the `stats` command:

```
stats "output.txt" every ::::0 using 2:3
```

The `every ::::0` restricts the command to the first row, and with the `using` statement you get statistics of the specified expressions. In your case the value of the second column is stored in the `STATS_min_x` variable, the third column in the `STATS_min_y` variable.

To plot both graphs in one, you only need to use a single `plot` command, the two graphs separated by a comma. The full script then looks like follows:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 1280,960

set xlabel "seq number"
set ylabel "timestamp"

set title "ts vs sequence number"

set key reverse Left outside
set grid

set pointsize 1.0
set style data linespoints

stats "output.txt" every ::::0 using 2:3

set output 'erf_ts_plot.png'
plot "output.txt" using 1:($2 - STATS_min_x) title "erf_ts",\
     "" using 1:($3 - STATS_min_y) title "ixia_ts"
```

The result is:

[image]

I assumed, that the `ts` is the subscript, which then must be in brackets in order to be set as such. Otherwise only the `t` is the subscript.

Comment: Do we need special package for stats command? If I type stats on my system it says command not found.I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I can't find stats command.I tried googling and it wasn't much of a help.

Comment: @liv2hak The `stats` command was introduced in gnuplot version 4.6. If you have an older version, you can use e.g. `head` to extract the first row. Replace the line with the `stats` call with: `row1 = system('head -1 output.txt'); STATS_min_x = real(word(row1, 2)); STATS_min_y = real(word(row1, 3))`. Here I used the same variable names as in my answer, although they are not approriate `;)`.